# OO design for intrusive data structure

Tags: c++, oop

I'm writing an intrusive linked list

```
class ListAlgorithm {
    ListNode& next(ListNode& n) {
        //returns an object of type ListNode linked to n.
    }
};
```

Users usually want to add some features (such as some additional data) on ListNode like this:

```
class UserNode : public ListNode {
    void operationOnUserData();
    int userData;
};
```

Then users have to downcast ListNode returned by 'next' into UserNode. It is inconvenient. Thus, I tried to make ListAlgorithm a template class :

```
//U extends ListNode
template<class U>
class ListAlgorihtm {
    U& next(U& u);
};
```

But then I have to upcast u into ListNode inside the method 'next' because class U could accidentally hide some members of ListNode that ListAlgorithm uses. This is error-prone because I could forget the upcast and compiler will not warn about that. I have to downcast ListNode into U again for the return value but it is safe because 'next' takes an instance u of U and the return value is something from u.

Another trial is

```
//U extends ListNode
template<class U>
class ListAlgorhtm {
    U& next(ListNode& n);
};
```

In this case, the upcast problem is not there, but I have to downcast ListNode into U for the return value and it is not safe because it is not sure that n is an instance of U. It could be an instance of another type extending ListNode.

What is the best solution in this case? I think this is a very elementary design problem and I'd like to know what kind of material I have to study for basic OO design like this.

Comment: Stroustrup does a good in depth exaplanation of this problem on the 4th edition of The C++ Programming Language.

Comment: @Manu343726, Thanks. The book has huge volume. Could you let me know the chapter?

Comment: I don't remember the exact chapter, maybe just before the matrix class design? On the templates and inheritance chapter I think. He talks about CRTP, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actual problem here is that you allow users to subclass `ListNode` and mess with its semantics by adding arbitrary data and operations to `ListNode` objects *through subclassing*. This therefore makes it necessary for the user to interpret the `ListNode&` return values of actual `ListNode` methods as something that those return values *are not*, semantically speaking.

This problem of a semantic nature is reflected in how tedious your code suddenly becomes, with casts and templating of an unrelated class (`ListAlgorithm`) which is due to your problem "propagating" and infecting other parts of your code.

Here's a solution: a `ListNode` object should not be allowed to **also be** a `UserNode` object. However, it should be allowed to **have, to carry with it** a `UserData` object that can be retrieved and manipulated.

In other words, your list becomes a simple container template, like `std::list`, and the users can specify the operations and data members that they need as part of the definition of the class they use as the template argument.

```
class IListNode
{
    public:
        // whatever public methods you want here

    protected:
        // pure virtual methods maybe?
};

class ListNode : public IListNode
{
    // List node class, no data
};

template<class UserDataType>
class ListNodeWithData : public IListNode
{
    private:
        UserDataType data;

    public:
        ListNodeWithData <UserDataType>(UserDataType &data) :
            data(data)
        { }

        const UserDataType& getData() {
            return data;
        }
};

class ListAlgorithm
{
    public:
        template<class UserDataType>
        ListNodeWithData<UserDataType>& next(const ListNodeWithData<UserDataType>& node) {
            // Do stuff
        }

        ListNode& next(const ListNode& node) {
            // Do stuff, which may be very similar to the stuff done above
            // in which case you may want to prefer to just define the
            // method below, and remove this one and the one above:
        }

        // You should define either this method or the two above, but having
        // them all is possible too, if you find a use for it
        IListNode& next(const IListNode& node) {
            // Do generic stuff
        }
};
```

As far as the size of the resulting classes is concerned, I just know it will increase if you use virtual methods in IListNode.

Comment: Thank you. I got your point. I have another question. My actual situation is somewhat different with linked list in my original question. It is not a 'container'. Sometimes users may not want to add their own data. The actual class corresponding to ListNode is standalone and also extendable. So, if a user does not add his own data, 1 byte of memory is wasted and he has to use a meaningless template parameter in your design. In this case, what is your suggestion?

Comment: @strugi _So, if a user does not add his own data, 1 byte of memory is wasted_: Why one byte? Let me add my suggestion in my answer.

Comment: @ madshogo, As far as I know, an empty struct like 'struct S {};' takes 1 byte.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the issue you raise goes, any time you want to operate on members of a class and avoid hiding by a derived class, just make sure your operations are on the base, so

```
template<class U>
class ListAlgorihtm {
public:
  U& next(U& u) {
    return static_cast<U&>(return nextNode(u));
  }

private:
  ListNode& nextNode(ListNode& n);
};
```

That said, you have a lot of options for this problem set.  The Boost library has an "intrusive" library that embeds node information either as `base_hook` (as a base of the user data) or `member_hook` (as a member of the class, which avoids some of the problems you describe).  Check it out at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/intrusive.html.